# How to include the local hostname as parameter in a GET URL?

Tags: linux, url, kiosk

I am working on an IoT project, having multiple clients in kiosk mode, opening a single URL. I want to create session but instead of manually entered username, I would like to use the client hostname automatically inserted in the URL as parameter to authenticate the session.
Any ideas how can this be achieved?

Comment: Explain how you connect to the URL and what is prompting for credentials. Maybe use expect?

Comment: I am going to use a raspbery pi in kiosk mode with chromium browser. The URL is the one that the kiosk will load as described in this guide:
https://desertbot.io/blog/raspberry-pi-touchscreen-kiosk-setup

Answer (score 0):

When you configure openbox, you will set the environment variable KIOSK_URL.  This will need to be set on each kiosk to its private login.  For example:

```
KIOSK_URL=https://www.example.com/login?user=foo&key=password
```

When Chromium does the get request on `https://www.example.com/login` it will pass the parameters that you provide.  Change user and key to the parameter names in the login form, and foo and password to your name and correcthorsebatterystaple.